# Do encoders/decoders preserve composition?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow, linear-algebra, autoencoders

Let's assume that we have an encoder *E* and a decoder *D* implemented for instance as a Convolutional Encoder-Decoder, namely *ED*.
Let's take two inputs *X* and *Y*, and some composition operator *o* operating on *X* and *Y*. The operation *o* consists in blending two images *X* and *Y* into a new image *X o Y* by averaging each two pixels from *X* and *Y*. Here, the images are RGB images with 28x28 pixels, represented by tensors of the form [28, 28, 3].

If we pass *X* o *Y* as input to (the encoder-side) *ED*, can (the decoder-side of) *ED* yield an output *ED(X) o ED(Y)* such that *ED(X) o ED(Y) = ED(X o Y)* ?

Is this always true or do we have to train the networks in a way that ensures such composition property?

I am not sure how to put it, but I am trying to reason about the composition law *f(x o y)=f(x) o f(y)* in terms of the encoder-decoder architecture.

Thanks

Comment: I think this question needs some clarification of the context, your terminology, the conditions you're assuming, etc.

Comment: Updated. I hope it helps.

Comment: The question is unclear. Please **specify** which composition operation you're referring to. It's not at all clear what "merging" two images means. What image is $X o Y$? Also, what sort of shape is [?, 28, 28, 3]? Did you mean [28, 28, 3]?

Comment: @DeltaIV I don’t have any specific composition in mind. I mean it in the mathematical sense. It could be blending, or any arithmetic operation of the two tensor representations of the images. I am leaving the definition of *o* broad because it might affect the existence of the composition law that I seek.

Comment: Unless you define the allowed operations on your images, i.e., unless we define some sort of algebra or group on the space of images, the question is obviously too broad and should be closed.

Comment: @DeltaIV let’s say we define the operation as averaging over the pixels of the two images.

Comment: Good. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @DeltaIV I did.

Comment: Very well. I upvoted your question accordingly.